# Sorting a custom data type

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

So I would like to sort a list of persons comparing them on the second element of the tuple.

```
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.Ord (comparing)


data Person = Person (Int, Int) Color deriving (Eq, Show)

getCoordBlockY :: Person-> Int
getCoordBlockY (Person (a,b) _ ) = b

sortPersons :: [Person] -> [Person]
sortPersons lijst = sortBy (compare `on` (  getCoordPersonY . )) lijst
```

But this doesn't compile. How would I go about doing this in Haskell?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: What if you use ``compare `on` getCoordBlockY`` instead of ``compare `on` (  getCoordPersonY . )``?

Comment: Is `getCoordPersonY` a typo for `getCoordBlockY`? If not, you should include its definition.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have some misunderstanding on how [**`on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on), `on` basically is implemented like:

```
on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
on f g x y = f (g x) (g y)
```

This function thus "preprocesses" the values with a function `g :: a -> b`, and then calls `f` on the two preprocessed parameters.

If you thus write:

```
on compare getCoordBlockY :: Person -> Person -> Ordering
```

you thus first obtain the *y*-coordinate of the two `Person` objects, and then compare these.

You thus can implement your sorting function like:

```
sortPersons :: [Person] -> [Person]
sortPersons = sortBy (on compare getCoordPersonY)
```

As [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52915806/sorting-a-custom-data-type/52915881?noredirect=1#comment92742519_52915881) comments, you can also use [**`comparing :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> a -> a -> Ordering`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#v:comparing), which is defined as:

```
comparing :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> a -> a -> Ordering
comparing = on compare
```

so a shorter version of `sortPersons` is:

```
sortPersons :: [Person] -> [Person]
sortPersons = sortBy (comparing getCoordPersonY)
```

Comment: Also, [`comparing`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#v:comparing) `= on compare`